# SQL Server Query regarding to find all tables with Date when Last record updated Or Inserted

Tags: sql-server

I need to find all the tables order by date in descending order of last updated or inserted rows. Is there any query regarding this?

I am trying with below query but it's giving me only schema updated tables. But I think `modify_date` is related to schema only.

```
SELECT
[name] AS [UserTableName]
, create_date AS [CreatedDate]
, modify_date AS [ModifiedDate]
FROM sys.objects
WHERE [type] = 'U' --to only display ‘USER_TABLE’
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't store the details of when a row in a table was last inserted or updated. You need to store this yourself. Do you store this meta data anywhere? If the answer is "no", then you cannot get the information you want.

Comment: A commonly adopted convention is to have columns such as `CreateDate`, `AlteredDate` on tables where you require to audit this kind of activity.

Comment: There are a lot of caveats with this but in the absence of anything else it can give some idea... `SELECT MAX(last_user_update) as last_user_update, OBJECT_NAME(object_id) FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats WHERE last_user_update IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY object_id`